# Converting NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I have an `NSDate` (lets call it `x`), `12 September, 2012 10:18PM (GMT)`. I want to convert `x` to a minute before my current time zone's (EST) midnight. So, x represented in `EST` with `NSDateFormatter` after conversion would be `12 September, 2012 11:59PM (EST)`. What's the best way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: From the top of my head, use a `NSDateComponents` object, and set its `TimeZone` to EST, and components to 23 for the hour, 59 for the minutes, and the rest from the date given. Then, allocate an `NSCalendar` with `Gregorian` identifier, and get the final date:`dateFromComponents:`... Or wait for a proper answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at NSDateComponents: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I believe you'll need to convert the NSDate to NSDateComponents, set the time to 11:59PM, then convert back to NSDate.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
[components setHour:23];
[components setMinute:59];
NSDate *convertedDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

NSLog(@"date=%@, convertedDate=%@", date, convertedDate);
```

Comment: +1 yup, that's how I'd put it. Just add `setTimeZone:` to specify `EST`.

Comment: Does this take into account the localTimezone or converts the date to a minute before midnight only with reference to GMT?

Comment: Yes, from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000185-SW1 : "By default, NSCalendar uses the default time zone for the application—or process—when the calendar object is created. Unless the default time zone has been otherwise set, it is the time zone set in System Preferences."

Answer (score 2):

Such manipulations can be easily done with the numeric representation of a date. In this representation, you deal with the number of seconds since a reference date.

The reference date for the purpose of the `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` is January 1<sup>st</sup>, 2001, at 00:00:00 GMT.

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSInteger secondsSinceReferenceDate = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
secondsSinceReferenceDate += 86400 - (secondsSinceReferenceDate % 86400);
secondsSinceReferenceDate -= 60;
secondsSinceReferenceDate -= [NSTimeZone.localTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSDate* justBeforeToday =
    [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:secondsSinceReferenceDate];

NSLog(@"Date used was %@", date);
NSLog(@"Just before tomorrow is %@", justBeforeToday);
```

Since there are 86400 seconds in a day (24 hours times 60 minutes 60 times 60 seconds = 86400 seconds), you know that `86400 - (secondsSinceReferenceDate % 86400)` is the number of seconds there are still to midnight. So if you take today's date (or any other valid date), add this number of seconds, and then subtract another 60 seconds, you'll have today's evening at 11:59 PM in the GMT timezone.

With `[NSTimeZone.localTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:]`, you know how many seconds your timezone is offset from the GMT timezone. By subtracting this offset to your integer representation, you effectively get when it will be 11:59 PM in your local timezone.

Here's a sample output:

```
Date used was 2012-09-12 22:37:49 +0000
Just before tomorrow is 2012-09-13 03:59:00 +0000
```

I'm in the EDT timezone too, and this looks like the correct answer (remember Standard Time is -5 from GMT, but right now we're in daylight savings, so it's -4 from GMT, which is invariant).

Comment: Does this take into account timezones? The input NSDate is GMT, the output NSDate is GMT as well, but when converted to current timezone will yield a minute before midnight in current timezone.

Comment: @0xSina, I misread a number of things in your question and I'll post an update shortly.

Comment: @zsneak: should you not use `secondsFromGMTForDate:` so as correctly to allow for daylight savings?

Comment: @zneak thanks for the answer, i really liked it, but jrc's answer is much simpler that's why i accepted his, but thanks again!!